# Should the search box always be placed in the upper right corner?

Tags: search

I placed the search box close to the results, so the user knows he is searching within the results and not globally. Is this a good approach?

[image: http://i47.tinypic.com/2zzhlde.gif]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the search box is related to the items list at the right side of the page, it's great to leave it there. Because it really looks like a filter feature.

But if the search box take the user to another page with different results (that weren't in the first list), it shouldn't be there, 'cause in this case it wouldn't be a filter.

Comment: It's related to the items list at the right side.

Comment: Then, it's ok to leave it there. Actually, it has to be placed in that filter box. ;)

Comment: The convention is, afaik, upper-right corner for global site-search functionality, and then close to the content if its a search interface to the current page (like you have in your question).